# Wordpress not using correct comments file?

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anyone with experience using Wordpress know why it would not use my `comments.php` file that is in a theme folder?

Comment: Do you have `<?php comments_template(); ?>` in your `single.php` file?

Comment: @Doug Neiner  yes I do, somehow it is not loading the file though, it is loading a comment post form from somewhere else and I can't find where it is even coming from.

Comment: did you managed to work it? I'm having same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working now, I had to change

`<?php comments_template(); ?>`

into this

```
<?php comments_template('', true); ?>
```

instead, weird but it fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

If you already have `<?php comments_template(); ?>` in place (which you do) then it could be a file permission issue.

Also, it is probably pulling from `classic` or `default` if it can't read your `comments.php` file in the current directory of your theme.

Make sure your `comments.php` has the same permissions as the rest of your theme files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the following in your template's single.php to include comments:

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

Use the default template that comes with WordPress as a reference.

Doug Neiner added this as a comment first so if he posts it as an answer please choose his.

Comment: Yes I have <?php comments_template(); ?> in single.php but somehow it is like bypassing it and loading a different comment post form from some unknown location, I been searching all day to see where it is puling it from, I even tried deleting every other theme and directly linking to the correct comment file and still does not seem to work the way it should

Comment: it is acting as if it has cached an old comment.php file and is using it instead but I don't see any cache files anywhere so I dont think that is the case

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution.
Problem that my theme not using single.php while it loads. So adding **comments_template('', true);** not helping.

So I added it to my index.php file and it appears now like it should.

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done with the comments_template function:

```
<?php comments_template($file, $separate_comments); ?>
```

**$file** is the file name you want to load (for example, "/comments.php"). It's an optional parameter.

**$separate_comments** is used to set whether to separate the comments by comment type. It's boolean, and the default is FALSE. It's an optional parameter (if you omit it, it's set to FALSE).

**NOTE**: This only works for single posts and pages. To make it work everywhere, set **$withcomments** to "1".

If you want to create your own custom comment template (like for a custom theme), call it like this, for example ("short-comments" is just an example name):

```
<?php comments_template( '/short-comments.php' ); ?>
```

If you've done all this and WP still isn't using the correct comments.php, check file permissions. **Also--hacking comments is a common problem, so someone may have hacked your site and caused a problem with the file.**